# Reverse proxy setup using nginx for a web app running on node.js+mongodb+basic Html and CSS in Docker=> Not working

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx

I wan to use reverse proxy to serve my website on public ip address. But when I am accessing the address I am getting just default nginx page.
Here is docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: visualization_app
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    links:
      - database
  database:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27011:27017"
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.17
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ../nginx_conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./public:/srv/www/static
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Here is my nginx conf file:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    root /srv/www/static;
    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header    Host    $http_host;
        client_max_body_size 17m;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as build-stage
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
CMD ["server.js","store.js"]
```

I am trying to configure this setup since 3 days but nothing seems to working. Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a server_name directive inside your server block: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/ Also, the proxy_pass can't be set to localhost, it needs to be set to the name of the container you're directing traffic to.

Comment: Thanks it works. A small mistake costed me 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy pass needs to point to the host of the application. Try with:

```
proxy_pass          http://app:4000;
```